# Converting a boolean expression tree to a series of bitwise operations

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I'm looking for an algorithm to convert a boolean expression tree into an optimal set of bitwise operations where the boolean inputs are indicated by bits in a word.

eg: suppose a set of bit flags like this:

```
enum
{
    Apples = 1 << 0,
    Pears = 1 << 1,
    Bananas = 1 << 2,
}
```

and suppose an expression like this:

```
Apples && (Pears || Bananas)
```

has been parsed into an expression tree like this:

```
    
AND
 |
 +-- Apples
 |
 +-- OR
      |
      +-- Pears
      |
      +-- Bananas
```

How would one convert that AST to an optimal set of bitmask/test operations?

A general algorithm would be great, but in my use case most of the expressions are testing each bit as either set or clear and can be reduced to and bitwise test in the form `((input & mask) == test)`.  eg:

```
Apples && Pears && !Bananas
```

can be evaluated as

```
(input & (Apples|Pears|Bananas)) == (Apples|Pears)
```

The only operators I need to support are boolean AND, OR and NOT.

I'll probably sit down and figure this out myself but thought it was an interesting problem that I've not seen discussed before. I'm wondering if there are existing solutions or if anyone has suggestions for how to approach it.

Comment: If you haven’t figured it out yet: You are using Boolean operators, so all your enums are non-zero therefore treated as “true”, and the end result is “true”.

Comment: @gnasher729 - I think you missed the point of the question, but maybe I didn't explain it well.  Try the linked article for a better explanation: https://www.toptensoftware.com/blog/bitmask-expressions/

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out and even wrote an .NET IL generator to generate code from the optimized execution plans.  It's too much to explain here, but [wrote an article about it](https://www.toptensoftware.com/blog/bitmask-expressions/).

Also, full code can be [found here](https://github.com/toptensoftware/BitmaskExpressions/)